# Why do I get this 'Erase is backspace' message after I do a reset in xterm?

Tags: terminal, arch-linux, xterm

So when I do a reset in xterm I get something like this:

> Erase is backspace.
>
> [omarg@computer]:

I've already checked my `.bashrc` and `.Xdefaults` files but it doesn't seem like that message is being invoked from there.

Notes:

- When I do a reset in a TTY I don't get that message.
- Arch Linux user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message comes from `reset` itself, have a look at [the source](https://github.com/alexmac/alcextra/blob/master/ncurses-5.9/progs/tset.c#L1321) or to be more precise the [`report`](https://github.com/alexmac/alcextra/blob/master/ncurses-5.9/progs/tset.c#L1079) function.

Please be aware that the official homepage is http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ and not the linked repository.

Comment: Woah thanks a lot, `reset -Q` did the trick. It's just a matter of creating an alias. (:

Answer (score 0):

For me the way to make that message go away was:

```
stty erase '^?'
```

as per: [Backspace and CTRL commands print question marks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177272/backspace-and-ctrl-commands-print-question-marks)

When that message shows up for me, it means that my backspace is broken and rather shows up as `^?`. `stty erase '^?'` both fixes backspace and makes the warning go away.