# Backspace and CTRL commands print question marks

Tags: gentoo, console

I've run into a peculiar issue on a fresh gentoo install. Within the console, the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key prints an adorable little question mark inscribed within a square instead of its intended function. Also, I've found that <kbd>Tab</kbd> behaves in exactly the same way, in addition to any <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> commands. The keys worked perfectly fine during the install, but after booting into the system proper and performing initial setup, they seem to have just given up.

`localectl` status outputs the following:

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.utf8 
               LC_COLLATE=C 
    VC Keymap: us 
   X11 Layout: us 
    X11 Model: pc105+inet 
  X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

Basically, I can't use the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys in console and haven't yet installed x11. I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: An easy way to fix will be by using the `stty` command.  For example, to fix backspace, you can type `stty erase <backspace_key>`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unxnut. I issued the command and received the following output

stty: invalid integer argument '?' (where '?' is my backspace key)

Comment: Hit `<ctrl v>` before hitting the backspace key.

Answer (score 1):

Ran out of space as a comment..

For backspace, `stty erase '^?'` should get you what you want.

When you say CTRL commands aren't working, do you mean <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>? If so, what about `stty intr ^C`? Can you still switch terminals with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>? In any case, it may be helpful to paste the output of `stty -a`

The following link should be helpful when it comes to stty settings:
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch05_08.htm

Also, another question: since you're using the `localectl` command, does that mean you're running `systemd`? Did the install disk use `systemd` or `openRC`? I'm pretty sure it's `openRC` and that might be why it worked in the installer and not in the OS.

Answer (score 1):

The question-mark-in-a-box is the Unicode replacement character.  The Linux console will print that in two cases:

- the character is not in the currently-loaded font (512 glyphs), or
- the display-controls feature has been enabled in the console.

The latter has been in the kernel quite a while, as seen in [this link to console.c in 2.2.26](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/console.c?v=2.2.26#L1869), which has the relevant comment:

```
1869                 /* If the original code was a control character we
1870                  * only allow a glyph to be displayed if the code is
1871                  * not normally used (such as for cursor movement) or
1872                  * if the disp_ctrl mode has been explicitly enabled.
1873                  * Certain characters (as given by the CTRL_ALWAYS
1874                  * bitmap) are always displayed as control characters,
1875                  * as the console would be pretty useless without
1876                  * them; to display an arbitrary font position use the
1877                  * direct-to-font zone in UTF-8 mode.
1878                  */
```

and it is set by either of [two escape sequences](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/console.c?v=2.2.26#L1051):

```
1051                         case 11: /* ANSI X3.64-1979 (SCO-ish?)
1052                                   * Select first alternate font, lets
1053                                   * chars < 32 be displayed as ROM chars.
1054                                   */
1055                                 translate = set_translate(IBMPC_MAP,currcons);
1056                                 disp_ctrl = 1;
1057                                 toggle_meta = 0;
1058                                 break;
1059                         case 12: /* ANSI X3.64-1979 (SCO-ish?)
1060                                   * Select second alternate font, toggle
1061                                   * high bit before displaying as ROM char.
1062                                   */
1063                                 translate = set_translate(IBMPC_MAP,currcons);
1064                                 disp_ctrl = 1;
1065                                 toggle_meta = 1;
1066                                 break;
```

and [**reset** by a third](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/console.c?v=2.2.26#L1040):

```
1040                         case 10: /* ANSI X3.64-1979 (SCO-ish?)
1041                                   * Select primary font, don't display
1042                                   * control chars if defined, don't set
1043                                   * bit 8 on output.
1044                                   */
1045                                 translate = set_translate(charset == 0
1046                                                 ? G0_charset
1047                                                 : G1_charset,currcons);
1048                                 disp_ctrl = 0;
1049                                 toggle_meta = 0;
1050                                 break;
```

The last (if `TERM` is **`linux`**) can be scripted as

```
tput rmpch
```

using this feature:

```
   exit_pc_charset_mode      rmpch    S3   Exit PC character
                                           display mode
```

or

```
tput sgr0
```

but *not* the `reset` or `stty` commands.

Further reading:

- [console_codes - Linux console escape and control sequences](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html)
- terminfo building block [klone+sgr](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-klone_sgr), containing `rmpch`
- [terminfo - terminal capability data base](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html)